# Trying to solve Sum of Digits / Digital Root with JS but having issue, please can any one explain it

Tags: javascript

1. solving Sum of Digits / Digital Root and facing problem in this case where input is 010 the output comes 8.
   please can anyone explain?

```
function fun(n) {
  let numString = n.toString().split("");
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numString.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(numString[i]);
  }
  console.log(sum);
  if (sum >= 10) {
    return fun(sum);
  }
  console.log(numString);
  return sum;
}
console.log(fun(010)); // input- 010 and output- 8
```

Why the output is 8 but it should be 1.

Comment: because in JavaScript, a number with a leading 0 is treated as an octal, so `010`  evaluates to `8` (try `console.log(010)`)

Comment: Can you send link which can explain more about it so that I can get better understanding. How can I remove this issue if vale is give like 010 or 015.

Comment: There are two links that explain it at the top of the post, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#octal_numbers) is another. To deal with this issue you would need to pass your values into your function as strings to begin with: "010".

Comment: Thank You for the link and explanation.